# Matrix on both sides of an equation with no inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I'm stuck when it comes to solving equations with matrices on both sides when the matrices contain no inverses (so they cannot be cancelled out).

For example, $$\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}1&3\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
(i.e., no inverse)
and $\mathbf y = [a,b]$

I'm looking for all solutions to $\mathbf A\mathbf y = \mathbf A\mathbf u$ in the form $\mathbf u=c\mathbf v+\mathbf w$, but I'm confused on where to start if the $\mathbf A$'s can't be cancelled.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{v}$? What is $\mathbf{w}$?

Comment: What's $x$ or $c$?

Comment: Sorry, v and w are vectors, c is any real number

Comment: $\mathbf{Ay}=\mathbf{Au}$ if and only if $\mathbf{Ay}-\mathbf{Au} = \mathbf{0}$, if and only if $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{u}) = \mathbf{0}$. So a first step would be to figure out what are all the solutions to $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a+3b\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
We have the same for $\mathbf u=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}$:$$\mathbf A\mathbf u=\begin{bmatrix}u_1+3u_2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
The $\mathbf y$ is a solution if $a+3b=u_1+3u_2$. Then we can express $a$ as $$a=u_1+3u_2-3b$$
Therefore $$\mathbf y=\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}u_1+3u_2-3b\\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}u_1+3u_2\\ 0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-3b\\ b\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf A\mathbf u+\begin{bmatrix}-3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}b$$
To identify with your notation $c=b$, $\mathbf v=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, and $w=\mathbf A\mathbf u$